# GreenPlum SQL query to convert into Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

Below query we want to convert greeenplum SQL to hive sql, kindly help us.

GP sub query :

```
select a.region , amount_fr , count_fr , amount_sr , count_sr from (
select region , sum(cast(amount as integer)) as amount_fr , count(transid) as count_fr  from test.test_fr_imi
where cast(trans_date as date) between (select cast(add_months(trunc(date_sub(cast(current_date as date),1),'MM'),-1) as date) ) and
(select current_date::date  - 1 - substring((select (date_trunc('month',current_date::date ))::date - 1)::character varying,9,10)::integer)
  group by 1 ) a
JOIN
(select region , sum(amount::integer) as amount_sr , count(transid) as count_sr from test.test_sr_imi
where trans_date::date between (select (date_trunc('month',current_date::date - 1) - interval '1 month')::date) and
(select current_date::date  - 1 - substring((select (date_trunc('month',current_date::date ))::date - 1)::character varying,9,10)::integer) group by 1 ) b on
a.region = b.region;
```

I needs to convert above query which is sub query not able to convert to hive, please find particular code as above one.

> (select current_date::date  - 1 - substring((select
> (date_trunc('month',current_date::date ))::date - 1)::character
> varying,9,10)::integer)

```
select to_char(round((select sum(revenue)/1000000.00 from test.sampletable where trxn_date = current_date-1)/1, 2) ,'999,999')

select to_char(round((select sum(case when to_char(trxn_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char((current_date - 1) - '1 month'::interval, 'yyyymm') and extract(day from trxn_date) < extract(day from current_date) then revenue end)/1000000.00 from test.sample2table)/1, 2) ,'999,999')

select to_char(round ((select(( ( sum(case when to_char(trxn_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char((current_date - 1), 'yyyymm') then revenue end))  -   (sum(case when to_char(trxn_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char((current_date - 1) - '1 month'::interval, 'yyyymm') and extract(day from trxn_date) < extract(day from current_date)  then revenue end) )) / (sum(case when to_char(trxn_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char((current_date - 1) - '1 month'::interval, 'yyyymm') and extract(day from trxn_date) < extract(day from current_date) then revenue end) ))*100.00 from test.sample3table)/1, 2) ,'9990.99%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some helps on some functions -

1. round() - available in hive.
2. to_char(INT,'999,999') - You can use `format_number(12345,0)` - this will result 12,345
3. CURRENT_DATE- available in hive.
4. CURRENT_DATE-1 - This can be done using  `current_date - interval '1' day`.
5. Syntax in hive is a little different. You need to put your sql in a subquery adn the calculate on top of it.

So, here is equivalent of first sql-

```
SELECT format_number(round(sum_rev/1, 2), 0)
FROM 
    (SELECT sum(revenue)/1000000.00 as sum_rev
     FROM test.sampletable
     WHERE trxn_date = CURRENT_DATE- interval '1' day) rs
```

here is equivalent sql of second query

```
SELECT format_number(round(sum_rev/1, 2), 0) 
FROM (SELECT sum(CASE
                                       WHEN from_timestamp(trxn_date, 'yyyyMM') = from_timestamp((CURRENT_DATE - interval '1' day) - interval '1' month, 'yyyyMM')
                                            AND extract(DAY
                                                        FROM trxn_date) < extract(DAY
                                                                                  FROM CURRENT_DATE) THEN revenue
                                   END)/1000000.00 as sum_rev
                        FROM test.sample2table) rs
```

Comment: (select current_date::date  - 1 - substring((select (date_trunc('month',current_date::date ))::date - 1)::character varying,9,10)::integer)

Comment: how do we converted with sub query

Comment: select cast(date_sub(cast(current_date as date),1) - substring((select cast(date_sub(cast(trunc(cast(current_date as date),'MM')as date),1) as string),9,10)) as bigint)

Comment: i tried but sub query not allowing

Comment: have you tried first query in my answer? if you got error pls let me know?

Comment: it looks like multiple you are looking for multiple SQLs. could you pls edit your question and ask which one you want help on?

Comment: yes, thanks for your help and it is working

Comment: select
format_number(round(sum_data_usage_5340/1, 2), 0)
from 
(select round(sum(data_usage_5340)/(1024.00*1024.00*1024.00*1024.00),0) as sum_data_usage_5340
from tmp.data_usage_5340 
where timestamp = current_date) rs

Comment: i converted as you gave input based

Comment: glad that it worked.

Comment: i have edited questions and please help me sub query based GP to convert hive.

Comment: i dont understand this. the query changed totally. again, i can see another question on same subquery. can you pls focus on original query and its answer ?

Comment: @karthikelavan Please avoid editing initial questions after someone helped you and you said that it worked. Ask another question and consider accepting/upvoting this one. When you constantly editing questions it is wasting of our time. And do not forget to accept/upvote if it worked, this is how to say 'thank you it worked' on this site.

Comment: @leftjoin - sorry for inconvenience and apologies

Comment: I think @leftjoin is very precisely vented out my feelings. Pls dont move the target, it takes time and effort to answer and when you change the question completely, it gets frustrating to answer. Create a new one pls when you need another help. Thanks and happy learning!